# Android TextView: text not shown if setText from HTML and android:singleLine="true"

Tags: android, html, textview

I'm setting a text to a TextView calling

`tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + text + "</a>"));`

This text is a web link.

This was working fine till I cut the text by myself.
Now that I've set:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

to the TextView, the text is not visible anymore.

Is it a known issue or what ?

EDIT:

To let others better understand the problem, I explain in details what was happening:

This was my TextView:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEventRecipient"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/elv_title_1_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />
```

This the code where I set the text as link:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventRecipient); 
String userName = "<a user name got from somewhere>";

// here I was cutting the userName as it's length must fit 
if (userName.length() > 16)
    userName = userName.substring(0, 15) + "…";

// here I set the link to the user
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + userName + "</a>"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This was working but with a horrible fixed `16` as max length so I decided to make it more dynamic with the "singleLine".

The `singleLine="true"` is causing the problem not showing the text as HTML link.

Comment: "I cut the text by myself" -- what does this mean? Also note that `android:singleLine` is deprecated. Use `android:maxLines="1"`.

Comment: `if (userName.length() > 16)
        userName = userName.substring(0, 15) + "…";`

Comment: There is no `userName` in the `setText()` call in your question. Please edit your question to show us **exactly the code that is not working for you**.

Comment: There's no need to edit, you solved the problem. `android:maxLines="1"` works, thanks. Anyway, sorry, I was too short: **userName** was my `text` and this is what I was cutting.

Comment: @CommonsWare: ok, edited to let others understand better. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:singleLine` has been more-or-less deprecated for a while. It only infrequently works. `android:maxLines="1"` is more typical nowadays.